# Dictionary in Swift not working?

Tags: iphone, swift, dictionary, bluetooth, ibeacon

The point of this function is to determine the closest beacon. If you run this code, the print statement `"THING WAS SET TO 0 THIS SHOULD ONLY HAPPEN AT FIRST"` prints over and over and over.

I don't understand why this is happening. Is there something about dictionaries here that I don't understand? Shouldn't setting the value of the dictionary at each beacon to 0 initially, make it such that at any future time the value of the dictionary evaluated at said beacon should be ZERO and NOT NIL??

I have three beacons sitting on the table in front me when I run the code on my iPhone 6S. I have been sitting here trying to solve this pretty much the entire day.

Also, the dictionary is initially empty and ignore the timer code.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    if beaconsHaveBeenFound == false {
        self.timeOutTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(30, target: self, selector: "locationDeterminationHasTimedOut:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    print("beacons were found")
    for beacon in beacons {
        if nearestBeaconsDictionary.indexForKey(beacon) == nil {
            print("THING WAS SET TO 0 THIS SHOULD ONLY HAPPEN AT FIRST")
            nearestBeaconsDictionary[beacon] = 0
        } 
    }

    nearestBeaconsDictionary[beacons.first!] = nearestBeaconsDictionary[beacons.first!]! + 1
    self.beaconsHaveBeenFound = true

    for beaconIntPair in nearestBeaconsDictionary {
        if beaconIntPair.1 == 60 {
            self.timeOutTimer.invalidate()
            self.beaconsHaveBeenFound = false
            print("a beacon has been verified 60 times")
            self.nearestBeacon = beaconIntPair.0
            let myUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: "B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D")
            let myRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: myUUID!, identifier: "CompanyBeacons")
            manager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(myRegion)
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("foundNearestBeacon", object: nil)
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "refreshRequested:", name: "refreshRequested", object: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `nearestBeaconsDictionary` declared?

Comment: As a property of the delegate. All this code is in the delegate.

Comment: Can you explain why you are calling `indexForKey`? That is a _very_ unusual thing to do!

Comment: To determine if the key already exists in the dictionary... indexForKey returns nil if there is no such key, or at least I read that this is true.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code is using a `CLBeacon` object as a key to a Swift `Dictionary`, and expecting it to match another `CLBeacon` object from a previous ranging callback.  This won't work.

Why?  Because two `CLBeacon` objects are not necessarily equal (as defined by the `Hashable` protocol, which Swift uses for `Dictionary` keys) even though they have the same identifiers.  The objects have other fields like `accuracy` and `rssi` that vary.  As a result, `nearestBeaconsDictionary.indexForKey(beacon)` will always return false, because from the `Hashable` perspective, each beacon it encounters is always different.

The solution is to use a different key for the `Dictionary`.  I often define a method like this:

```
func keyForBeacon(beacon: CLBeacon) -> String {
  return "\(beacon.proximityUUID) \(beacon.major) \(beacon.minor)"
}
```

Then the code can be changed to:

```
if nearestBeaconsDictionary.indexForKey(keyForBeacon(beacon)) == nil {
  print("THING WAS SET TO 0 THIS SHOULD ONLY HAPPEN AT FIRST")
  nearestBeaconsDictionary[keyForBeacon(beacon)] = 0
}
```

Comment: I love you. I completely forgot that each CLBeacon object was different even if it was the same beacon. You have no idea how much effort has gone into this. You have saved my LIFE!!!!